# How to use the Sqoop get result is only one file in hdfs

Tags: hdfs, sqoop

How to use the Sqoop 1.4.5(mysql --> hdfs), get result is only one file in hdfs?
thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the docs (sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html) or some blogs (http://www.ingest.tips) for more information on using Sqoop1 or Sqoop2.

Comment: hi! I don't found what in the docs, I'm using Sqoop1 1.4.5. My results is  /Sqoop/1.4.3/part-m-00000
 /Sqoop/1.4.3/part-m-00001a
 /Sqoop/1.4.3/part-m-00002
 /Sqoop/1.4.3/part-m-00003 ...in hdfs. I want the results is 1 part in hdfs. How to do? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either merge the files creating a new larger file  or you can set the number of mappers to 1 using -m 1 or --num-mappers 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I was excuted the sqoop again, it's new one part file another.

Comment: I has three table datas in mysql, I want these dates to three part files in hdfs, and rename.

Comment: I'd ask this on the sqoop user mailing list: http://sqoop.apache.org/mail-lists.html.